# Is there any enforcement on a transaction output being associated with an address?

Tags: stealth-address

As far as I understand, Monero allows Alice to create a public key for Bob that only Bob knows, on the fly, by using the following mechanism:

Bob's address:  *A* = *aG*, *B* = *bG*, where only Bob knows *a* and *b*.

Alice's creation:  *R* = *rG*, *P* = *h(rA)G + B*

This allows Bob to know that the private key of *P* is equal to *h(aR) + b*.

My question is, **is this key creation process enforced?**

For example, could Alice send money to a different *P* that is in no way associated with an address *A* and *B*, and is instead an arbitrary *P = xG* and simply generating a random unassociated *R*?  Or is there a mechanism that I am not aware of that somehow prevents this?

My suspicion is that this is a valid maneuver, as it doesn't violate any of the unlinkability protections and is, as far as I know, undetectable.

EDIT:  Just to be clear, this *P = xG* has not been used before.

EDIT 2:  I should clarify that *x* can be a value known by Bob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this key creation process enforced?

There is no protocol level enforcement beyond *P* and *R* being points on the curve.

> For example, could Alice send money to a different P that is in no way associated with an address A and B, and is instead an arbitrary P = xG and simply generating a random unassociated R?

So yes, in theory at least, Alice could manually construct a transaction with output key *P* and transaction key *R* as you described.

Comment: Would it be burning the money?  If Bob (or Alice) knew _x_?  I thought the only thing needed for a transaction was the private key and _R_ was only needed to find the key.

Comment: If the random x was persisted then no, funds wouldn't be burnt.